# How can 'enable selection' in a gridview be activated programatically in vb?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gridview

I'm using visualStudio 2010 vb

When using Gridview, you can extend the cotextual menu and select 'enable selection' and this will create a select link (which can be changed to button) in each row, which this this allow to select the row and triger, for example, a drill down of the information contained in the row.

Can this 'enable selection' be activated programatically?

I tried the following without any result:

GridView1.AutoGenerateSelectButton = True

Thanks

c

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the databind. The following works

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateSelectButton = True
GridView1.DataBind()
```